# Find list of terms indexed by Lucene

Tags: lucene

Is it possible to extract the list of all the terms in a Lucene index as a list of strings? I couldn't find that functionality in the doc. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lucene 3:

- C#: [C# Lucene get all the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892494/c-sharp-lucene-get-all-the-index)
- Java:

  ```
  IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(path); 
  TermEnum termEnum = indexReader.terms(); 
  while (termEnum.next()) { 
      Term term = termEnum.term(); 
      System.out.println(term.text()); 
  }
  termEnum.close(); 
  indexReader.close();
  ```
- Java (all terms for a specific field): [How can I get the list of unique terms from a specific field in Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910008/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-unique-terms-from-a-specific-field-in-lucene)
- Python: [Finding a single fields terms with Lucene (PyLucene)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091028/finding-a-single-fields-terms-with-lucene-pylucene)

Answer (score 17):

In Lucene 4 (and 5):

```
 Terms terms = SlowCompositeReaderWrapper.wrap(directoryReader).terms("field");
```

Edit:

This seems to be the 'correct' way now (Lucene 6 and up):

```
LuceneDictionary ld = new LuceneDictionary( indexReader, "field" );
BytesRefIterator iterator = ld.getWordsIterator();
BytesRef byteRef = null;
while ( ( byteRef = iterator.next() ) != null )
{
    String term = byteRef.utf8ToString();
}
```

Comment: Assuming the field name is `"field".` In Jackrabbit it is `"_:FULLTEXT".`

Comment: @RobAu `SlowCompositeReaderWrapper` is now deprecated in 6.1.0. Would you know how to do it in 6.4.1?

Comment: Lucene teams seems to make a very bad habit of deprecating things without updating the Javadoc to point people to the new ways or methods!