# How to get all indexed terms from a large Lucene.Net index?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

How can I retrieve all of the indexed (but not stored) terms for a large index in Lucene.Net?

The reason I am doing this is because I am moving from Lucene.Net to the latest Apache Lucene release, and the index format has changed a number of times over the releases. I am migrating the data by reading in the terms and then indexing them again to the new format. I am aware of the Lucene codecs package, but that does not offer backwards compatibility far enough back for the format used by Lucene.Net.

There are similar questions, e.g. [Find list of terms indexed by Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148036/find-list-of-terms-indexed-by-lucene)

However, the problem with the above approach is that `IndexReader.Terms` reads every single term from the index and this causes an `OutOfMemoryException` on large indexes.

How can I get all of the terms from a large index in a sane manner without risking running out of memory?

Example code (that throws `OutOfMemoryException` on the call to `reader.Terms(orderBy)`):

```
var results = new List<string>();
var orderBy = new Term("MyField", string.Empty);
using (var reader = IndexReader.Open(FSDirectory.Open(_indexPath), true))
using (var termEnum = reader.Terms(orderBy))
{
    for (var term = termEnum.Term; term != null; termEnum.Next(), term = termEnum.Term)
    {
        if (term.Field != "MyField")
        {
            break;
        }
        results.Add(term.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, it seems the only reason you might run out of memory in this scenario is because you are writing all of the terms into a `List<string>`. To avoid running out of memory, you should instead persist the strings to disk.

```
var orderBy = new Term("MyField", string.Empty);
using (var reader = IndexReader.Open(FSDirectory.Open(_indexPath), true))
using (var termEnum = reader.Terms(orderBy))
using (var stream = new FileStream("TheFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    for (var term = termEnum.Term; term != null; termEnum.Next(), term = termEnum.Term)
    {
        if (term.Field != "MyField")
        {
            break;
        }
        writer.WriteLine(term.Text);
    }
}
```

> While this may answer your question, the fact that you are trying to pull more terms out of the index than you have memory for is a sign that you are asking the wrong question. I suggest you ask another question that exemplifies the actual task you are trying to do - most likely there is a better (more efficient) way to do it than to read all of this raw data from the index.